# How to echo selected value of dropdown in php?

Tags: php

I want to echo selected value from dropdown. But it always give me the output: Default

Kindly check what I am doing:

```
   <div>
    <select id="orderStatus" name="orderStatus">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="Available">Available</option>
    <option value="Arranging Product">Arranging Product</option>
    <option value="Awaiting Fulfillment">Awaiting Fulfillment</option>
    <option value="Awaiting Payment">Awaiting Payment</option>
    <option value="Awaiting Pickup">Awaiting Pickup</option>
    <option value="Awaiting Shipment">Awaiting Shipment</option>
    </select>

     // I think here is the problem when I click button it forgets selected index value    
      <a href="order.php"  class="btn btn-large">Update</a>

   </div>
```

Php Code:

```
<?php
  $draft = isset($_GET['orderStatus'])? $_GET['orderStatus'] : 'DEFAULT';
  echo $draft;
?>
```

When I click on update button then in the output I always get DEFAULT. I think when I click on the update button it forgets the selected index value.

Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: the updatebutton should be a forn-submitting button like `<input type="submit" value="Update">` - and the whole thing should be wrapped in a form. Right now your 'button' is just a link, which doesn't submit the form and it's inputs/selects. This is why you receive nothing in php.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the reply. Working with <input> and <button>. But I have to use <a> to use href="order.php"

Comment: the `href` of an anchor `<a>` is the `action` in a form -> `<form action="order.php" method="GET">`

Comment: all of your questions that have potential solutions should be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Add to tag  onmousedown event:

```
   <div>
    <select id="orderStatus" name="orderStatus">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="Available">Available</option>
    <option value="Arranging Product">Arranging Product</option>
    <option value="Awaiting Fulfillment">Awaiting Fulfillment</option>
    <option value="Awaiting Payment">Awaiting Payment</option>
    <option value="Awaiting Pickup">Awaiting Pickup</option>
    <option value="Awaiting Shipment">Awaiting Shipment</option>
    </select>

     // I think here is the problem when I click button it forgets selected index value    
      <a href="order.php" onmousedown="this.href=this.href+'?orderStatus='+document.getElementById('orderStatus').value" class="btn btn-large">Update</a>

   </div>
```

This send your parametr as GET request

Comment: what if I send the link via tabselect + enter?

Comment: @Vladimir Thanks for the reply. But unfortunately not working.

Comment: HTML code works fine - https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVIVESBBWV6O

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
    <form method="GET" action="order.php">
        <select id="orderStatus" name="orderStatus">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="Available">Available</option>
            <option value="Arranging Product">Arranging Product</option>
            <option value="Awaiting Fulfillment">Awaiting Fulfillment</option>
            <option value="Awaiting Payment">Awaiting Payment</option>
            <option value="Awaiting Pickup">Awaiting Pickup</option>
            <option value="Awaiting Shipment">Awaiting Shipment</option>
        </select>

        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-large">Update</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This , Its working :

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$value = $_POST['orderStatus'];
echo $value;
}
?>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <select id="orderStatus" name="orderStatus">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="Available">Available</option>
        <option value="Arranging Product">Arranging Product</option>
        <option value="Awaiting Fulfillment">Awaiting Fulfillment</option>
        <option value="Awaiting Payment">Awaiting Payment</option>
        <option value="Awaiting Pickup">Awaiting Pickup</option>
        <option value="Awaiting Shipment">Awaiting Shipment</option>
        </select>


          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />

       </form>
```